# What is the best way to optimize my Windows-7 services for WAMP?

Tags: windows-7, services, wamp

Any recommendations on the best services to run (or not run) on a Windows-7 machine when running WAMP?

I feel like I have most of the background tasks minimal so I can get the full use. (3% usage)

What utilities can I run to help get a bit more juice out of my machine?

Answer (score 0):

Äh - do nothing?

Talking about software. Seriously.

> I feel like I have most of the
>   background tasks minimal so I can get
>   the full use.

What is the sense behind it?  I mean, seriously - you want full stack performance, DO NOT USE THE SYSTEM INTERACTIVELY. Servies normally do not use a lot of CPU anyway unless used.

> What utilities can I run to help get a
>   bit more juice out of my machine?

There is the one called "credit card". Get a faster disc, more memory, faster CPU.

Software wise - try overclocking.

Besides that there simply is no need to tune at all to start with.

Comment: If this is a dev-machine, you DO have to be able to use the machine interactively while the stack is running.
Also, there is no guarantee he's using Windows Server (doesn't sound like it), so there are definitely a lot of things you can kill in the background.

Comment: @Fake very correct. I am TESTING code, not serving it. And Windows Server? Whats the point when WAMP runs Apache?